# How to effectively use the animal traps?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I'm playing campaign mode for Black Ops 2, and I've come to the point in the Pyrrhic Victory mission that grants me the animal traps from the small wooden shed.

I've placed the bear traps around the pathway, but they don't exactly seem to slow anyone down.  Is there an effective location to place the traps that will make the mission easier?  Also, are the traps able to hurt me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the part after you have alerted the whole village, you have to run back.

While you are running, plant the animal traps down. Try to put them near places of cover, as that gives you a high chance of a enemy stepping on them.

The traps are not able to hurt you. Just don't get distracted when placing them.